# How do I change text depending on where I am in my scrollview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a makeshift custom "actionbar" at the top of my view, and a scrollView beneath it.

I was wondering if there is anyway to change the text displayed in the bar at the top depending on what is currently visible at my current position in my scrollView.

***ANSWER***

Make sure you have made your ViewController a ScrollView delegate, it should look like this:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate>
```

Once you have declared your ScrollView inside your .h file and synthesised it in the .m file make sure you tell it that it's delegate is itself:

```
ScrollView.delegate = self;
```

Then use the following method to detect where you are in your current scrollview

```
- (void) scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scroll {
    if(scroll.contentOffset.y > /*Your Y coordinate*/){
        // What you want to do when it reaches your y coordinate.
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement `UIScrollViewDelegate`, and use the `scrollViewDidScroll` function. This will notify you every time the scrollView is scrolled. You can get the current location of the scrollView, and update your text accordingly.

More help on [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios//documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIScrollViewDelegate/scrollViewDidScroll:)

Comment: In the -scrollViewDidScroll method implementation it's probably easiest to use the -visibleCells method of your tableview to get an array of what is visible on the screen now.

Comment: @MarkusDheus, I agree. But the question seems to be just about the `UIScrollView`. If the op changes the question, I will surely update my answer as you advised. :)

Comment: Oops. Didn't see that, thanks for pointing it out... Too many questions about UITableViews ;-)

Comment: I'm not using a tableview, do you have an equivalent method in scrollView?

Comment: @JamesWolfe This method is indeed on `UIScrollView`.

Comment: @JamesWolfe Also, the `UITableView` inherits from `UIScrollView`, and `UITableViewDelegate` inherits from `UIScrollViewDelegate`.

Comment: Doesn't matter I figured it out, using scrollView.contentOffset.y variable within the UIScrollViewDidScoll function. Thanks everyone :)